# How to force latex to completely use the previous page before moving to next page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, page-breaking

[image: Snapshot of the end of page 57 of the book and the start of page 58]

In the figure attached, the end of the page 57 of the book I'm writing is shown. The page margin for the bottom I've set is 1cm, and as can be seen there is much space left at the bottom of page 57 and instead of filling the page completely, latex starts a new page. This happens to lots of pages in the book and I want it fixed everywhere with little piece of code (preferably in the preamble). Can anyone help me out?

Comment: by default display math does not break, assuming you are using `amsmath` you can issue `\allowdisplaybreaks` to allow breaking

Comment: However your "acceleration of Amoeba" looks like a heading, latex should never normally break a page after a section heading. there is presumably something wrong with your markup, but you have shown no code, so impossible to say what you should change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle \allowdisplaybreaks solves the problem. Thank you very much. I'm new to latex, just started with it a week ago (had to urgently write a book within 10 days). I've a very bad code in the preamble (maybe many packages unused, or interfering each others), lots of warnings coming up while main.tex builds up, but I'm ignoring these for the sake of urgency.
Is there a way I can check what packages are interfering each other and/or unused in my document?
And, Thanks very much Again for your help sir!

Comment: impossible to say in that generality. The usual advice is always _not_ to start with some big complicated preamble copied from somewhere, always start from an _empty_ preamble and just add packages when you know you need the feature and then problem of knowing unused packages does not arise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default display math does not break, assuming you are using `amsmath` you can issue `\allowdisplaybreaks` to allow breaking